# Android Room, query with empty params

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have an Android app that uses Room.
I have the following query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM model WHERE (:someInt is null)")
List<Model> myQuery(Integer someInt);
```

However, when I call it with a null value, it returns an empty List.
The following test fails.

```
    List<Model> models = myDao.myQuery(null);
    assertFalse(models.isEmpty());
```

In the other hand when I try it using the following query it returns items.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM model WHERE (:someInt is not null)")
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

I'm using Room 2.2.5.

Thanks,

Comment: You probably would need direct access to the prepared statement API here, and I'm not sure if SQLite prepared statements would even support this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've seen some posts where this seems possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079052/room-could-i-check-passing-value-to-query-for-null and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029435/optional-query-parameters-for-android-room